# LibGDX Collision scoring system increases continuosly

Tags: java, android, libgdx, collision, scoring

I am developing a game. When my main character intersects with a star(point), I should get 1 point.
I used Intersector.overlaps but when both are intersected, score is increasing continuosly until they don't touch each other. How can i fix it? I initialized int score = 0, and here my collision code,

(starAvailable = I am removing star from screen after collision. Not an important thing for scoring.)

```
            if (Intersector.overlaps(charCircle,starCircles1[i])) {
                starAvailable1=false;
                    score++;
            }
```

[For example, when i intersect with a star, score is becoming like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF3Nv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (starAvailable = I am removing star from screen after collision. Not an important thing for scoring.)

It is actually important. The easiest and most efficient way you have to do this is to remove (or move away out of the visible field, disable... whatever you are doing to save memory) the star straight before or after changing the score, so make sure you will not trigger further collisions. There is not enough code to know how to do it in your project, but something like...

```
if (Intersector.overlaps(charCircle,starCircles1[i])) {
            //starAvailable1=false;
            removeStarFromField(); // we disable the collider, stop rendering,
                                   // or remove the star
            score++;
}
```

As a less effective alternative, but which may be more accessible if you have not a lot of experiece with LibGdx, and if your star has some sort of unique identifier or you can add it to it, is you could store which stars you collided with (or if you already collided with one specific star, if you are caching them).  Once you collide with the star, you cache that identifier. You then should check the id fromt he star you hit against your cache, and if it's there, you shouldn't increase the score, something akin to:

```
// somewhere else...
Set<String> identifiersFromAlreadyHitStars = new HashSet<>();

....

// then your actual collision detection method
if (Intersector.overlaps(charCircle,starCircles1[i])) {
            if(!identifiersFromAlreadyHitStars.contains(hitStar.identifier){
        score++;
       identifiersFromAlreadyHitStars.add(hitStar.identifier)
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually I generated a boolean to remove stars from screen. Initial starAvailable is "true". At the beginning, star is created, after collision starAvailable becomes "false" so it removed from screen. Then before render it again, I change it to "true" before drawing so again drawing process starts. I have 6 different stars looping in the screen, and game is hard so its easy for me doing like that. My problem is scoring increases continuously until it disappears because of the overlaps I guess.  @HaroldH

Comment: You must make sure you move the stars *right after* their are collided, otherwise they are prone to count 1 point per rendered frame.

Comment: Is there no other way ?

Comment: As long as the element is there and is collideable, you will have that issue.

You could also flag them so their collision is ignored based on a flag, for example. There are many ways of doing this, but the root of it is: you must be able to ignore elements you already collided with, flagging or modifying them somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding starCircles[i].setX(1500).

```
            if (Intersector.overlaps(charCircle,starCircles1[i])) {
            starAvailable1=false;
            starCircles1[i].setX(1500);
            score++;
        }
```

Stars are coming continuosly and updated in each loop, so circle's setX value is updating again after looping.

Now score is increasing by 1 for each star collision.

Comment: If the idea of moving the stars away from the playing field was taken from the answer I made in which it was one of the recommendatinos, it may be useful for others to mark it as accepted, and adding your solution to your own question as an edit or addendum.